# Get x and y coordinate in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, article, sections

I have `section` and `article` for displaying contents. My code is:

```
<section id = "examples">

 <article id="item_1">
    ...
 </article>

 <article id="item_2">
  ...
 </article>

 <article id="item_3">
    ...
 </article>

 <article id="item_4">
  ...
 </article>

 ...

</section>
```

How can I get the x and y co-ordinates of all the `articles`?

Comment: Is JQuery acceptable?

Comment: @Jacek It was tagged with jQuery ;)

Comment: @Jacek its on his tags

Comment: Ahahaha, thx :). Sorry for missing that point :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with jQuery using [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) or [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
$('article').each(function(){
     var position = $(this).position();
     console.log("top: " + position.top + " left: " + position.left);
});
```

[**LIVING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y36y2/)

Take into account that `position` is relative to the document and `offset` calculates the coordinates relative to the parent offset element.

Answer (score 3):

Easy to do with jQuery

```
$('article').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var position = element.position();
    console.log( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
}
```

you can use instead pure js as @koningdavid pointed out in the same way

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    var element = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log( "left: " + element.left + ", top: " + element.top );
}
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/HMHbE/1/

Answer (score 2):

Pure Javascript method

```
document.querySelector('#item_1').getBoundingClientRect() // for example for #item_1
```

**element.getBoundingClientRect**

The returned value is a TextRectangle object which is the union of the rectangles returned by getClientRects() for the element, i.e., the CSS border-boxes associated with the element.

The returned value is a TextRectangle object, which contains read-only left, top, right and bottom properties describing the border-box, in pixels, with the top-left relative to the top-left of the viewport.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

Comment: You still need to loop through the articles.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this in javascript:

```
// element is each article
// then you can use element.top and element.left for the x and y
var element = document.getElementById('Item_1');
var ele = element.getBoundingClientRect();:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getBoundingClientRect() javascript function

```
 var div = document.getElementById("item_1");
 var position = div.getBoundingClientRect();
 alert("Coordinates: " + position.left + "px," + position.right+"px,"+ position.top + "px," + position.bottom + "px" );
```